# Div borders overlap with float elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a layout for a project. I have two div containers(leftnav and rightnav) which are floated on left and right. I have to divide the central part into two. "Mailbar" is the upper div in that central region. The problem is that applying borders to "mailbar" div overlaps with the floating div. I want to prevent it from overlapping.

```css
#main {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#leftbar {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
#rightbar {
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
#mailbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="leftbar"> </div>

    <div id="rightbar"> </div>

    <div id="mailbar"> </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @troyer how it will work??? he used float not position

Comment: Can you make the problem visible in your snippet?

Comment: Why dont try with %? :) Look: https://jsfiddle.net/3jjpasum/2/

Comment: Agree with @Troyer, your design will not be perfect in all browsers with fix pixel size

Comment: @Troyer That's a good idea to play with width and margin. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use % to define the width of the `navbars`, then the remaining % to `mailbar` and add the width of the left `navbar` to `mailbar` as `margin-left`.

For example:

https://jsfiddle.net/3jjpasum/2/

```
#main {
    margin:0px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#leftbar {
    float:left;
    width: 15%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#rightbar {
    float:right;
    width:15%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
#mailbar {
  margin-left: 15%;
    width:70%;
    height:50%;
  background-color: red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: +1 vote for fast and reliable answer. Still i dont think `margin-left: 15%` is better than `float: left;`

Comment: Thank you @KirankumarDafda, `float:left` would do de job too, personally I like more the exact % of the sidebar :)

Comment: Yes, it is. Every developer have their own choice and styles :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `width: 100%;` and add `overflow: auto;` for `#mailbar`.

```css
#main {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#leftbar {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
#rightbar {
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
#mailbar {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
<div id="leftbar"> </div>

<div id="rightbar"> </div>

<div id="mailbar"> </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:
use `box-sizing:border-box;` for child divs;
and `calc` for middle div

```
 #main {
      margin: 0px;
      height: 150px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    #leftbar {
      float: left;
      width: 250px;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: auto;
      border-right: 1px solid black;
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    #rightbar {
      float: right;
      width: 250px;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: auto;
      border-left: 1px solid black;
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    #mailbar {
      width: calc(100% - 500px);
      float:left;
      height: 50%;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed container as in this case. You can just use position absolute.

See example below.

```css
#main {
 margin:0px;
 height:150px;
        position:relative;
 border:1px solid black;
}
#leftbar {
 float:left;
 width:250px;
 height:100%;
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
 overflow-y: auto;
 border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#rightbar {
 width:250px;
 height:100%;
        position:absolute;
        right:0;
        top:0;
 overflow-y: auto;
 border-left: 1px solid black;

}
#mailbar {
   
        left:250px;
        right:250px;
 position:absolute;
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;
        height:50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id = "main">
<div id = "leftbar">
</div>

<div id = "rightbar">
</div>
<div id="mailbar"></div>
</div>
</body>
```